# Running multiple selenium tests simultaneously in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i locally run multiple selenium tests at the same time using node js?
I have tried combining **selenium-webdriver** and **async** but the tests only run as a series.

Am i missing something? Can someone provide an actual example? (dont just reference me to Selenium Grid or some framework)

Comment: Are you asking for parallel execution?

Comment: Yes i am --filler---